# Dojo Javascript variable scope

Tags: javascript, json, dojo, scope, dgrid

I am using [dgrid](http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/) and i am attempting to set the dataStore externally. When the page loads i call `aliasTicket.load()` to create the grid. At the time the grid is loading the `datasource` is null. When a query is executed the `setAliasSource(aliasData);` is set.

There are no errors however the grid is still empty. The aliasStore is being updated with data however it isn't being reflected on the grid even after the grid is refreshed. How can i get the data reflected in the grid after the query?

**Javascript Object**

```
   var aliasTicket = (function (){

    var aliasData = [];

    require([ "dojo/store/Observable", "dojo/store/Memory"]);   
    var aliasStore = new dojo.store.Observable(new dojo.store.Memory({
        data: aliasData,
        idProperty: "id"
      }));  

    return{         

        load:function(){

            require([
                     ........

                   ], function(declare, Memory, OnDemandGrid, ColumnSet, Selection,
                     selector, Keyboard, DijitRegistry, editor, ColumnHider,
                     registry, Observable,lang) {

                aliasData = this.aliasData;

                var Store = this.aliasStore = new dojo.store.Observable(new dojo.store.Memory({
                    data: aliasData,
                    idProperty: "id"
                  }));

                console.log(Store);

                var CustomAliasNameGrid = declare([OnDemandGrid, selector, Selection, Keyboard, editor, DijitRegistry, ColumnHider]);

                  var aliasNameGrid = new CustomAliasNameGrid({
                    store: Store,
                    columns: {
                      id: {
                        label: "Id",
                        field: "id",
                        hidden: true,
                        autoSizeColumn: true
                      },

                      employeeTicketId: {
                        label: "Employee Ticket Id",
                        field: "employeeTicketId",
                        hidden: true,
                        autoSizeColumn: true
                      },

                      chkBox: selector({}),


                      aliasName: {
                        label: "Alias Names",
                        field: "aliasTicketName",
                        autoSizeColumn: true,
                        formatter: function(str) {
                          return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt) {
                            return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
                          });
                        }
                      }

                    },
                    selectionMode: "none",
                    loadingMessage: "Loading data...",
                    noDataMessage: "No results found....",
                    allowSelectAll: true
                  }, "aliasNameGrid");  



                aliasNameGrid.refresh()

            }); 

        },

        setAliasSource: function (data){
            console.log(data);
            this.aliasSource = data;            

        },

        setAliasData: function (data){
            this.aliasData = data;              
        },

        getAliasSource: function (){

            return this.aliasSource;
        }       

    };  

})();
```

**Setting Data Store Data**

```
aliasData = [{.....},
             {.....},
             {......];          


            require(["dijit/dijit"]);
            aliasTicket.setAliasSource(aliasData);              
            dijit.byId('aliasNameGrid').refresh();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting 'this.Store' to an object array, not a real 'dojo store' object. Following your code I can not see where you actually use 'this.Store'. Inside the grid code I do see a local variable named 'Store'.

So I'm not sure if I'm following your code example here but, you should 'set' the store of the grid and then refresh it. Something like this.

```
 setAliasSource: function (data){
        console.log(data);
        this.Store = data;
        dijit.byId('aliasNameGrid').set("store",new dojo.store.Observable(new dojo.store.Memory({ data: data,idProperty: "id"}));
        dijit.byId('aliasNameGrid').refresh();

    },
```

Comment: I declared store in the load function 

var Store = this.aliasStore = new dojo.store.Observable(new dojo.store.Memory({
                    data: aliasData,
                    idProperty: "id"
                  }));

Comment: I think since load has been run first it needs to be run again for the data to be reflected however running load again may not be a good idea since the widget is already registered

Comment: It is not necessary to call refresh after calling set('store', ...) - that will already refresh for you.